# Powershell combining multiple objects into a table of information

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to create an export script. Within the script i create 3 PSObjects with a single column of information, lets say we have the 3 psobjects below:

```
Information1        
------------ 
Moreinfo1 
Moreinfo2 
Moreinfo3 

Information2
------------
Moreinfo4
Moreinfo5
Moreinfo6

Information3
------------
Moreinfo7
Moreinfo8
Moreinfo9
```

What i want is that i can combine these 3 PSobjects together into one single PSobject and align all information to the top. so the result will be something like this:

```
Information1        Information2         Information3
------------        -------------        -----------
Moreinfo1           Moreinfo1            Moreinfo1
Moreinfo2           Moreinfo2            Moreinfo2
Moreinfo3           Moreinfo3            Moreinfo3
```

i already tried several things like:

```
$ExportVariable = $Information1
$ExportVariable += $Information2
$ExportVariable += $Information3
```

This adds them together in one object, but does not align them to the top. It creates empty lines like this:

```
Information1        Information2         Information3
------------        -------------        -----------
Moreinfo1
Moreinfo2
Moreinfo3
                    Moreinfo4
                    Moreinfo5
                    Moreinfo6
                                          Moreinfo7
                                          Moreinfo8
                                          Moreinfo9
```

Can someone help me to get the result i want?

Comment: You should show the part of the script where you create the data.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
# create 3 PSObjects
$a = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Property1" = [string[]]::new(10) } 
$b = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Property2" = [string[]]::new(10) } 
$c = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Property3" = [string[]]::new(10) } 

# fill 3 PSObjects
0..9 | % { $a.Property1[$_] = $b.Property2[$_] = $c.Property3[$_] = "dummy" + $_.ToString() }


# consolidate 3 $PSObjects
$x = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Property1" = [string[]]::new(10); "Property2" = [string[]]::new(10); "Property3" = [string[]]::new(10); } 


# fill destination object
0..9 | % { $x.Property1[$_] = $a.Property1[$_]; $x.Property2[$_] = $b.Property2[$_]; $x.Property3[$_] = $c.Property3[$_]; }

$x
```

Comment: Thank you, this brings me one step closer to the solution. With this commands it creates the properties in the object, but the value under the properties is put into an array. Is it possible that this can be show as in the example, so that for every item in the array there is an extra line?